# create-react-app создаёт read-only директорию

Tags: reactjs, create-react-app

В терминале запускаю команду `create-react-app *название*`
Проект создаётся, но только в read-only, и как это дело изменить я не знаю.

Использую Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А вы через ls -la проверяли режим доступа к этой директории? Возможно там запрещена запись, тогда от рута надо chmod-ом ее добавить.

Answer (score 0):

Попробуй сделать выполнить с директории в которой находиться проект команду:

```
chmod -R 777 ./<dirname>
```

Таким образом ты изменишь права доступа на папку и на все что в ней находиться.